# Controls strangely shown when looped;

Tags: c#

My problem is this:

[image]

Those labels are created there via for loop and I think you got what my problem is,
that weird overlapping.

Code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < maxlabels ; i++)
{                
    Label x = new Label();
    x.Name = string.Format("label{0}", i);
    x.Top = 2 + (15 * i); // <---- changed this line
    x.Left = 3;
    x.Text = x.Name;
    x.BringToFront();
    x.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    panel1.Controls.Add(x);                
}
```

In the above code, when changed the

```
x.Top = 2 + (30 * i);
```

into

```
(15 * i);
```

i got the result:

[image]

Comment: the pannel is perhaps not big enought to display all the labels?

Comment: Change Height. x.Height = 15;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't explicitly set a Height on the Label it wull use the default.

You could solve this by setting `x.AutoSize = true;` and using the Labels Height in the multiplier

```
for (int i = 0; i < maxlabels ; i++)
{                
    Label x = new Label();
    x.Name = string.Format("label{0}", i);
    x.AutoSize = true;`
    x.Top = 2 + (x.Height * i);
    x.Left = 3;
    x.Text = x.Name;
    x.BringToFront();
    x.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    panel1.Controls.Add(x);                
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) easy solution :)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you  use FlowLayoutPanel. And set direction to top-down (you can do that in property UI also):

```
 yourFlowLayoutPanel.FlowDirection = System.Windows.Forms.FlowDirection.TopDown;
```

You will not need to set top, left etc in this panel:
e.g.

```
for (int i = 0; i < maxlabels ; i++)
{                
        Label x = new Label();
        x.Name = string.Format("label{0}", i);
        x.Text = x.Name;
        x.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        yourFlowLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(x);                
}
```